# Set other checkbox value & name when checkbox checked

Tags: jquery

I want to set a checkbox value on the next block html code based on the first checkbox. When I click location `loc` checkbox, it will set the value to `0` & name for `without-qr` class.  And when the `loc` checkbox is unchecked, the `without-qr` name would be removed.

I've tried like this, but still not working:

```js
$(".loc").change(function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    $(this).closest('.p-without-qr').next().find('.without-qr').val(0);
    $(this).closest('.p-without-qr').next().find('.without-qr').attr('name', 'qr[]');
  } else {
    $(this).closest('.p-without-qr').next().find('.without-qr').removeAttr("name");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<dd class="col-sm-4">
  <ul class="list-unstyled mb-0">
    <li class="d-inline-block mr-2 mb-1">
      <fieldset>
        <div class="checkbox">
          <input type="checkbox" name="location_id[]" class="checkbox-input loc" value="{{ $location->name }}" id="location">
          <label>
                  Location Name
               </label>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
    </li>
  </ul>
</dd>
<dd class="col-sm-5">
  <ul class="list-unstyled mb-0">
    <li class="d-inline-block mr-2 mb-1">
      <fieldset>
        <div class="checkbox p-without-qr">
          <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-input without-qr" id="{{ $loc->location_name }}">
          <label>
               Without QR
               </label>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
    </li>
  </ul>
</dd>
```

Comment: What is the expected outcome here?

Comment: [`closest`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) _"For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and **traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree.**"_ - that's not going to do anything like you want with the DOM structure given

Comment: Seems you need `this.closest("dd").next().find(".without-qr")`

Comment: there is no `next()` on `closest('.p-without-qr')`

Comment: @mplungjan, if it is not the last "dd" element

Comment: then it is ignored

Comment: yes, indeed. Your comment is indeed a step in the right direction

Comment: Note that an input without `name` attribute is invalid HTML or at least strange. why don't you set it  by default and for example disable the input?

Comment: sorry for late response everyone, and thanks for your help. It's working right now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your closest needs to go further

```
$(".loc").on("change", function() {
  const $nextDD = this.closest("dd").next(); 
  if ($nextDD) {
    const $withoutqr = $nextDD.find(".without-qr");
    if (this.checked) {
      $withoutqr.val(0);
      $withoutqr.attr('name', 'qr[]');
    } else {
      $withoutqr.removeAttr("name");
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

please try this and change the closest function value for finding next block HTML

```
$(".loc").change(function() {
  if($(this).is(':checked')) {
     $(this).closest('dd').next().find('.without-qr').val(0);
     $(this).closest('dd').next().find('.without-qr').attr('name', 'qr[]');
  }else{
     $(this).closest('dd').next().find('.without-qr').removeAttr("name");
  }
});
```

Comment: Please cache the elements